# A python function with a rarely needed argument

Tags: python

I want to write a module, which contains a functions `func`. Due to technical details, it needs an argument `tech`. Since `tech` is about technical details, `tech` has a default value and rarely needs any changes. I have come up with two ways to deal with it:

1. leave `tech` to be an argument of `func` with some default value. The problem is that I have many other functions calling this function, for example, `gunc`, `hunc` ... To allow users to change `tech`, all these calling functions `gunc`, `hunc` need `tech` arguments, which is so not concise.
2. make `tech` to be a global variable and allow users to change it. The problem here is that `func` is now vulnerable to side effects, which seems to be a bad design.

Then how should I deal with the `tech` argument?

**Edit**

To provide more information, as a comment points out, here's an example:

```
def func(room, tech):
    """
    calculate how many lights we need to illuminate a room
    param tech: True if the owner wants the room to be more bright, so
    add some lights. This is seldom used since most people are 
    satisfied.
    """
    # do calculation
    return result

def gunc(room):
    """
    calculate how much money it takes to light a room.
    """
    return result

# here's many other functions

def hunc(company)
    """
    calculate how much money it takes to run a company
    """
    for room in company.rooms:
        money += gunc(room)
    money += many many other costs
    return money
```

In this example, it does not make sense to include a `tech` argument in `hunc`. After all, what on earth does running a company have anything to do with how many lights a room's owner wants? Also, if `hunc` takes `tech` arguments, it must have to take an infinite number of other technical arguments, which is unacceptable.

Comment: I think example functions for `func`, `gunc`, and `hunc` would help me wrap my mind around this question.

Comment: Only if it makes sense for your application: make `Tech` a class, `Tech()` the instance with default values and let `hunc` & `func` be the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to want to keep track of state, but I'd avoid using a global variable. Instead, I would encapsulate the technical parameters in a class.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, bright=False):
        self.bright = bright

    @property
    def lights(self):
        if self.bright:
            return 42
        return 21

    @property
    def lighting_cost(self):
        return self.lights * 10


class Building:
    def __init__(self, rooms):
        self.rooms = rooms

    @property
    def total_lighting_cost(self):
        return sum(room.lighting_cost for room in self.rooms)


room_a = Room()
room_b = Room(bright=True)
building = Building([room_a, room_b])

print building.total_lighting_cost # 630 = 210 + 420
```

This uses properties, but they could easily be replaced with appropriately named methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want users calling `gunc` and `hunc` to be able to change `tech`, then you should include it as a default argument to those functions, too.

Though the default might be 'None', and if it's not set to something different, `gunc` and `hunc` call `func` without the `tech` parameter.

In that way, you only have to define the default value of `tech` once, in `func`, but you avoid the use of a global variable.

Example:

```
def func(tech=42):
    print(tech)


def gunc(my_param, tech=None):

    if tech:
        func(tech)
    else:
        func()


# call hunc with default tech
gunc('Hello')

# specify tech
gunc('Hello', tech=7)
```

Comment: +1, but it'd be a bit cleaner to have the default be `None` even on `func` itself, put `if tech is None: tech = 42` inside `func`, and then `gunc` and everyone else can always call `func(tech)` without needing a conditional.

Comment: Mmmm, might be right, but I think that the example above might be clearer to people reading and maintaining the code. Judgement call.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to litter `if/else`s everywhere `func` is being called, and forgetting to will cause problems. The other issue is that `gunc()` and `gunc(tech=None)` are equivalent, but `func()` and `func(tech=None)` aren't, which again leads to confusion and bugs.

Comment: If you don't bother including all the `if/else`, why don't you just set the default value for every function?

Comment: @ChongWang because then you have multiple definitions of the default value for `tech` all over the code base. That will almost certainly lead to bugs when someone forgets to update one of them...

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
default_value = 10 #an example,can be anything
called_tech_value = 9 #you decide
def func(tech = default_value,tech_for_calls = called_tech_value):
    pass
```

All you need to do is use the tech_for_calls variable in other functions.

Comment: I don't understand the answer fully. Do you have an example for `gunc`?

Comment: This makes no sense. How is `func` supposed to decide which version of `tech` to use?